# Do Loop in SAS SQL for Creating Column

Tags: sql, loops, sas

I am new to SAS and SQL. I have a task to create similar column but with different number.

For example: `| DATE | NAME | A1 | A2 | A3 | B |`

So I code in SAS like this

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE TEST AS
    SELECT DATE, NAME,
           DO i = 1 to 3
             0 AS A&i.,
           END
           1 as B
    FROM SOURCE;
QUIT;
```

When I run, I got this error

```
Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, (, *, **, +, ',', -, '.', /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, AND, EQ, 
               EQT, GE, GET, GT, GTT, LE, LET, LT, LTT, NE, NET, OR, ^=, |, ||, ~=.
```

I appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For someone who is new to the site, there is often a need to add a comment to improve upon the question, but in your case I thankfully found the opposite: it is asked nicely and clearly, it has the code you have tried, the code is formatted, you show the error message, also formatted, and the tags are appropriate. Well done. Further, you marked an answer correct (not everyone does) and thanked the respondent - good job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use [macro](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#macro-stmt.htm) code to generate column names depend on loop counter.
For example, in your case:

```
%macro create_table(); %macro d; %mend d;

PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE TEST AS
    SELECT DATE, NAME,
           %DO i = 1 %to 3;
             0 AS A&i.,
           %END;
           1 as B
    FROM SOURCE;
QUIT;

%mend create_table;

%create_table();
```

Output:

```
+-------+------+----+----+----+---+
| date  | name | A1 | A2 | A3 | B |
+-------+------+----+----+----+---+
```

In addition, there is another way to complete task. Use data step instead of `proc sql`:

```
data test(drop=i);
   set source;
   array a{3};
   do i=1 to 3;
      a{i} = 0;
   end;
   b=1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Data step `array` statement can be used to create variables (columns in SQL terminology) and initialize them.  The `retain` statement will initialize a variable (once) to a value that is maintained from output row to row.  This is different from `b=1;` which will perform the value assignment as each row is processed.

```
data want;
  set source;
  array a(3) (3*0);  /* initialization syntax, 3*0 means 3 zero (0) values */
  retain b 1;
run;
```

Variables created by the array statement are the array *name* suffixed with a sequential number starting from 1.  The name list syntax can be used in `array` to create variables with a different base name and sequence range. The name, such as

```
  array a(3) x7-x9 (3*0);
```